# Bootstrap's JS won't function/load in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I installed a basic react app

```
npx create-react-app appnamehere
```

I then installed bootstrap (tried both v4 and v5 too)

```
npm install bootstrap
```

then loaded them on my `App.js`

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min";
```

The `css` works, but the the `js` components like alerts, collapse, etc. doesn't work. Figured out that this is because the `js` files aren't in imported in my project - which is weird since I did in fact imported them. I tried the `CDN` method, changing my `index.html` with this instead:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>MyApp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Guess what, same thing. `CSS` works like charm, `JS` stuffs aren't working. Any ideas?

Comment: The bootstrap javascript is expecting a complete DOM-document when it initializes, that's just not the case with React. You may want to consider something like [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) to make the two libraries work together

Comment: @CerebralFart You mean like install `react-bootstrap` and use them altogether with bootstrap or like completely migrate my project to react-bootstrap?

Comment: i'd go with react-bootstrap or reactstrap, its easy to use

Comment: @DC37 you probably need to remove the vanilla bootstrap package to get the react version to work, but I haven't worked with bootstrap in a long while, so your mileage may vary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use react-bootstrap if you want to use it with React.
https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/

```
npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap
```

You can check out their documentation on how to use it. It is just like importing Components.